# Maximizing the area of a transformed rectangle within some bounds

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, linear-transformations

I need to solve this problem for a program I'm writing, but I'm struggling a bit with the maths behind it.

Given a rectangle $R_{max\_layout}$ and a $3\times 3$ transformation matrix $M_{transform}$, I need to calculate the size of the biggest (maximum area) rectangle which, after being transformed by $M_{transform}$, still fits entirely within $R_{max\_layout}$.

[image: Figure 1]
<sub>(source: [twistedlogik.net](http://twistedlogik.net/layout_figure1.png))</sub>

What matters for this problem is relative sizes, rather than positioning. I'm concerned with whether $R_{answer}$ *could* fit inside of $R_{max\_layout}$, not whether it actually *does* under a given transform. In other words, the figure below can be considered identical to the one above: $R_{answer}$ would clearly still fit if it was properly translated.

[image: Figure 2]
<sub>(source: [twistedlogik.net](http://twistedlogik.net/layout_figure2.png))</sub>

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: When you store the rectangle, is it safe to assume that you are storing the coordinates of all 4 vertices?

Comment: I'm not storing the coordinates, but it's trivial to retrieve them.

Comment: Do you want to move the rectangle into the larger area or verify it is there?